# String inside an if statement

Tags: c#

I'm new in C#

I've been searching a solution for this simple problem for 4 hours now...

I've set values to A and B and wrote:

```
        if (A == B) 
        { string HC = "even"; }
        else{ string HC = "not even"; }
        Console.WriteLine("{0} , {1} {2}" , A , B , HC );
```

inside the "if" statment the "HC" is underlined with green line: "the value 'HC' is assigned but its value is never used."

And in the writeline it is underlined in red:" the name 'HC' does not exist in the current context."

Comment: Well time to go read about scope and curly braces. Declare the variable before the `if`.

Comment: You are declaring your string inside an inner block, denoted by the `{}` brackets. Anything outside of those brackets cannot see `HC`. Declare your `string HC` before the `if`, and then just use assignment within the brackets, i.e. `HC = ...`

Comment: As you are defining HC inside a else clause, the ambit of HC is only inside that else. Define HS outside the if